# How can celery chained sub task executes with eta or countdown args?

Tags: python, celery

Current code:

```
def chained_task(foo, bar, start_time):
    return chain(task1.s(foo, bar), task2.s(eta=start_time)).apply_async()
```

But it seems task2 isn't executed at start_time. Is there any option to execute task2 with callback args and eta?

Answer (score 0):

Use countdown for chained tasks with timedelta for two dates and timezone (if you needed) in total seconds like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

YOUR_TIMEZONE = timezone(offset=timedelta(hours=0), name='UTC')

start_first_task = datetime(2022, 5, 28, 18, 59, tzinfo=YOUR_TIMEZONE)
start_second_task = datetime(2022, 5, 28, 19, 59, tzinfo=YOUR_TIMEZONE)
countdown = (start_second_task - start_first_task).total_seconds()

first_task_s = first_task.signature(*args, **kwargs) 
# The countdown applies with respect to the end of the 1st task in chain
second_task_s = second_task.signature(*args, **kwargs, countdown=countdown) 

chain = (first_task_s | second_task_s).apply_async(eta=start_first_task)
```